# How to output valid html5 with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm trying to properly validate external url from a codeigniter 3 view.

I have in my db an url like this :

```html
http://www.example.com/content.php?id=test&article=3
```

and i want to make a link like this one ->

```html
http://www.example.com/content.php?id=test&amp;article=3
```

I tried this :

```
<?php 
if (isset($c_url_redir)){
  $c_url_redir = 'http://www.example.com/content.php?id=test&article=3';
  echo anchor(htmlspecialchars($c_url_redir), "go", 'class="pure-button pure-button-primary" target="_blank"');
}
?>
```

but i have the same url as the first one.
Could you help me?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two url you want

Comment: and this is not related to HTML5

Comment: As said this is not limited to HTML5 (but HTML in general). What you are looking for, is probably PHP's `url_encode()` function.

Comment: when i use urlencode($url), codeigniter add localhost at the begin of the url...

Answer (score 0):

Try using url_encode() on just the get variables. Personally, I'd have the first part of the URL assigned to a variable then tack on the url_encoded get variables e.g.

```
$c_url_redir = 'http://www.example.com/content.php';
$get_variables = url_encode('id=test&article=3');

echo anchor($c_url_redir . '?' . $get_variables, "go", 'class="pure-button pure-button-primary" target="_blank"');
```